# saving a tree as preorder

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have created a binary search tree with `{2,5,3,4,9,1,7,...,100}` digits.

how can i save it as `preorder`?
thanks

EDIT: Consider I have `{ 3,7,1,2}`  and make a `binary search tree` with these digits and I want to save this tree as `preorder which is {3,1,2,7}`

Comment: How do you mean "save it as preorder?"

Comment: Is their a horde of you with the same homework question today? See [Pre-order to post-order traversal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537969/pre-order-to-post-order-traversal), although your question can't actually be solved unless the numbers given are in post-order.

Comment: @user Referring to your edit, there are many valid BST structures for a given list of values. So you don't have enough information to construct the pre-order traversal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeh here on [literateprograms](http://en.literateprograms.org/Binary_search_tree_%28Java%29#Traversal) :

```
public List<E> toList() {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
    treeToList(root, result);
    return result;
}

private void treeToList(Node<E> node, List<E> goal) {
    if (node != null) {
        treeToList(node.left, goal);
        goal.add(node.value);
        treeToList(node.right, goal);
    }
}
```

A complete [article on binary trees and PreOrder traversals](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c9/s4.html).

Comment: I don't think OP actually has the tree structure to begin with.

Comment: I have another question that when I make a binary search tree with 100 digits how can i save that BST and read it as preorder?

Comment: @user Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537969/pre-order-to-post-order-traversal . You can do this by storing the pre-order or post-order traversal, from which you can construct the original tree.

Comment: thanks I get it but I have another question that i will ask it with other topic.

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm prints all the nodes, one per line, 
of the subtree of the node at `v` in the binary tree `bt1.`

```
  public static void preorderPrintLines (BinaryTree bt1, BNode v) { 
          String s = bt1.elementAt(v).toString(); 
                             //the class for the element in the node 
                             //needs to have a toString() method 
          System.out.println (s);   // subtree root element printed

           if (bt1.isInternal(v))   { 
              BNode       p;   
               if (bt1.hasLeft(v)) { 
                                  p  = bt1.left(v); 
                                 preorderPrintLines (bt1, p ); }   
                            //We have just traversed tree of left child 
              if (bt1.hasRight(v)) { 
                                  p  = bt1.right(v); 
                                  preorderPrintLines (bt1, p );  }    
                  //We have just traversed tree of right child 
              } //end if 
}
```

source : [here](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~bradley/Lec20Cpsc331.pdf)